# Mailcatcher not working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mailcatcher

I am trying get mailcatcher working with my Rails 3.2.x app. Added mailcatcher gem and bundled, and...

## development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "localhost",
    port: 1025,
  }
```

I get the mailcatcher console at localhost:1080, but I get nothing when mails is sent. I am using delayed job, and can see delayed jobs being created and run, so I know the mails are being triggered in dev. What is my next step in troubleshooting this?

Comment: I had, superficially, the same problem. Turned out, my emails were missing a `from:` so they were silently swallowed. Perhaps there was something similar for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener. This worked out of the box for me.

Comment: You can also use MailCatcher in a docker container such as https://github.com/spaquet/alpinemailcatcher